# Django ImageField that generates multiple renditions

Tags: django, image, django-models

In the admin of my Django website I let admins upload images at a very high resolution. I want to automatically generate and store several renditions of each uploaded image at specific sizes, and then use the different sized renditions in different places on the website.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [django-imagekit](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Can your provide some sample of how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the image directly in your template and use `sorl` to generate the thumbnail or image at different size.

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1172/

You can also override the model save method, check this small script:

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1172/